# How to use rvest to extract information from the gnomad database

Tags: r, xml, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to extract some information from the gnomad database using `rvest`, despite following some tutorials I am not extracting the right information. The parameter for `html_nodes` comes from the `selectorgadget` extension on chrome. Below is the code I used. Appreciate any help to point out what I am doing wrong.

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(xml2)

link="https://gnomad.broadinstitute.org/region/1-55516868-55516908?dataset=gnomad_r3"
page=read_html(link)

varaints=page %>% html_nodes(".cmvTB span")%>% html_text()
```

The output should be a list of the variant IDs : `1-55516880-T-C`, `1-55516902-T-G`, `1-55516903-G-GC`, `1-55516905-C-CT`.

I also attempted to use the XML path of the whole table, but still not luck.

```
link <- "https://gnomad.broadinstitute.org/region/1-55516868-55516908?dataset=gnomad_r3"
page <- xml2::read_html(link)
dat <- rvest::html_nodes(page, "body")
tab <- xml2::xml_find_all(dat, '//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "bxQxTC", " " ))]//div')
```

Comment: Check out my answer to the followup post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72564554/post-request-with-httr2-package/72565896)